# Unexpected pattern match in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

After loading the following example in WinGHCI, I try to evaluate

```
father p1
father p2
father p3
```

all the three expressions produce the same value :

```
Person "John" "Huston"
```

how is it possible ?

if I uncomment the last line, I get the following warning :

```
test.hs:14:1: Warning:
Pattern match(es) are overlapped
In an equation for ‘father’: father p2 = ...
```

What's Happening ?

---

```
data Person = Person String String deriving (Show)

p1 :: Person
p1 = Person "Charlie" "Chapling"

p2 :: Person
p2 = Person "John" "Huston" 

p3 :: Person
p3 = Person "Frank" "Sinatra"

father :: Person -> Person

father p1 = p2

--father p2 = p3
```

Comment: what did you expect? p2 is global and is always returned as result of 'father'. you need to change the function to pattern mantch the input and depending on that to produce different output.

Comment: `father p1 = p2` is unrelated to the `p1` value declared before: it is equivalent to `father x = p2`, stating that `father` returns `p2` on every input. You probably want to use `father x | x == p1 = p2` and add `deriving (Eq,Show)` to `Person`.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the meaning of

```
father p1 = p2
```

The variable `p1` in this clause does not refer to the `p1` you previously defined.  Rather, it is a fresh variable and the clause matches any argument value.

You can use GHC 7.8's [pattern synonyms](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-synonyms) to do what you seem to be trying:

```
pattern P1 = Person "Charlie" "Chaplin"

p2 :: Person
p2 = Person "John" "Huston" 

p3 :: Person
p3 = Person "Frank" "Sinatra"

father :: Person -> Person
father P1 = p2
father _ = undefined
```

Code is untested, because I don't have an installation of GHC 7.8 handy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `p1` inside your function matches everything (you could write `x` too - it would not make any difference).

I think what you want to do is:

```
data Person = Person String String deriving (Show, Eq)

-- ... rest of your code - p1, p2, ...

father :: Person -> Person
father p
   | p == p1 = p2
   | p == p2 = p3
   | otherwise = undefined -- what do you want to do here?
```

I would suggest not using a function like this at all but to do redefine `Person` to include this information as well:

```
data Person = Person { givenName :: String, surName :: String, father :: Maybe Person }
   deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p1` variable in your `father` definition doesn't have anything to do with the global `p1`. Pattern matching always introduces new variables and never uses global ones. So, your definition is equivalent to this:

```
father aaa = p2
--father bbb = p3
```

You could use guards like this:

```
father p | p == p1 = p2
         | p == p2 = p3
```

I would also suggest ALWAYS using the compiler option `-Wall`. You might see some interesting warnings. In fact, they would at least point you in the right direction, so that you probably won't need to ask on SO.

Comment: watch out ... `Person` was not in `Eq` in the OPs question ^^